# velocity template - array not adding quotes - trying to create JSON array

Tags: java, velocity

I'm trying to create a JSON array:

```
#set ($arrayCarousel = [])
#foreach ($image in $product.images)
  #set ($index = $index + 1)
  $arrayCarousel.add("
    <div class='carousel__slide u-center'>
      <img id='${index}' data-code='${product.code}' class='main_image' src='${image}' data-count='$!{product.viewCount}' />
    </div>"
  )
#end

<script id="prog-img-${product.code}" type="text/cycle">
  ${arrayCarousel}
</script>
```

However, it doesn't create quotes around each array item. Pretty new to velocity templates, but trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
  $arrayCarousel.add("${esc.q}
    <div class='carousel__slide u-center'>
      <img id='${index}' data-code='${product.code}' class='main_image' src='${image}' data-count='$!{product.viewCount}' />
    </div>${esc.q}"
  )
```

where `esc` is a reference to a Velocity Tool [EscapeTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html).

What you are doing is adding a String to a Java List. That string is delimited by double quotes as usual. If you want the value to contain double quotes as well, you need to add them, escaped.

That code is incredibly brittle, however. If `product.code` or `image` contains a double quote, it will break your JSON.

Also, note that you are relying on `ArrayList.toString()` having a representation that is very similar to a valid JavaScript array. This also seems a bit fragile.